# Spring security url interceptor

Tags: spring-security, spring-social

I have spring security implemented in my application, and you can logged with twitter facebook o normal, if you sign in with your email and password there aren't any problem, but if you logged with twitter,the url interceptor  don't let see that page. 
I have this code when you logged with twitter in my controller in java.

```
Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userRegister.getEmail(), "ROLE_USER");
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

And this is my url:interceptor in my spring-security.xml

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/member/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
```

Anybody can help me?
Thanky yoU!

Comment: Are you using any SSO mechanism to achieve the same or just trying to access the member URL then it will not allow you to access the resource until you have User role.

Comment: My url interceptor don't allow access the member until you have User role.